# Can I move existing folder to a new TFS Team Project without losing history of changes?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

We have a TFS Team Project with too much data today, the number of folders has become prohibitive and for a number of other reasons (code review policies), would like to split it into multiple Team Projects.

The idea is the following:

1. Add Team Projects to the project collection
2. Move folders from the original team project to the new ones

So, if we start with the team project:

```
Project A
+- Folder A
+- Folder B
+- Folder C
```

We would like to end up with three separate team projects:

```
Project A
+- Folder A
Project B
+- Folder B
Project C
+- Folder C
```

Will the TFS history of modification be maintained after this operation? Can it be done with a simple TFS Move operation?

**EDIT**: We are using the latest TFS on-premise (at the time of writing, version 2022).

Comment: Just to confirm, you're running TFS on-prem, and _not_ using the Cloud-y Azure DevOps platform? If so, exactly what version of TFS are you using, and ...why aren't you using git-in-TFS?

Comment: Edited! Please see above.

Comment: You can't natively move code between different team projects. You'd need to use third-party utilities to replay the changesets in the new team project.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel: Can you name some?

Comment: Another approach is to not try to move the history, create new team projects, create new repos with current snapshots, and keep the original repo but make it read only. For defect research needs and for compliance needs, the history is still available. The switchover will be disruptive and should be carefully timed and planned.

Comment: Still waiting to know some tool names that can migrate the history of changes from @Daniel.

Comment: Don't wait on me. I answered your question (it's not possible natively) and gave you a suggestion (use third-party tools). You're capable of looking into the third-party tooling options available; similar questions have been asked here dozens of times, and modern search engines are great.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel but I don't know the term to search for: "TFS migration tool"? "TFS replicate changeset tool" or what?

Comment: Did you *try* those searches and look at the results and evaluate if the results are what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, and I didn't find that much, a part from [this tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration): we badly need a tool to complete this task and I don't understand why you can't do some names for us and all people that will have the same need in future.

Comment: @abenci Any current tool for migrating version control history will probably be using the REST API for the TFVC history. See the [Get Changesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get-changesets?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) documentation as an example.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan. Again I need to be able to find some of these tools, evaluate them, and reorganize our company repository. If you can't make product names, can you help me to give a name to these tools category? I don't know where to find them. Please provide some links.

Comment: What about duplicating the team project 3 times and "tf destroy" what I don't need? Would it work?

Comment: This is very much the wrong approach to the problem and I recommend that you get in touch with a specialist to help you! @DanielMann and I are specialists as we would need to really understand the outcome that you are trying to achieve rather than just the mechanics you have described.

There are no tools out there for splitting a TFVC repository folders into multiple folders while preserving history.